# Where is the code wrong?

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve this problem from the UVA Online Judge: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=2456

#### The problem statement

> A square number is an integer number whose square root is also an integer. For example 1, 4, 81 are
>   some square numbers. Given two numbers a and b you will have to find out how many square numbers
>   are there between a and b (inclusive).

#### The code I've attempted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long int num1, num2, count = 0;
    int t, i;

    while (1)
    {
        count = 0;
        scanf("%lld%lld", &num1, &num2);

        if (num1 == 0 && num2 == 0)
            break;
        for (; num1 * num1 <= num2; num1 ++)
            count++;

        printf("%lld\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### The Judge's Response

The Online submission process tells me that my code produces the wrong answer, but I'm not able to figure out why. Can anyone see the error in my code?

Comment: Please take the time to write out the problem statement, what your strategy is, and which answer you got… in your question.

Comment: And give an example of what *inputs* you used to get the wrong *output*. What does *the number of problem is 11461* mean?

Comment: @lurker: From the tag, They are referring to this problem: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=2456

Comment: Your algorithm is broken. Given the input `4 4`, you would return 0. However, the correct answer is 1.

Comment: You misunderstand the problem statement. You should find out how many numbers between `a` and `b` are `square numbers` not calculate the squares of the numbers. That means you have to calculate the square root of the numbers between `a` and `b`

Comment: @BillLynch thanks. Not very obvious. I'm not familiar with "uva.onlinejudge.org" so I had no idea what the tag was about.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that you misunderstand the problem statement.
You should *not* calculate the `square` of the numbers but the `square root`.
If the `square root` is an integer then and only then is it a `square number`.

Another way of getting the correct count is in fact calculating the `square` but not on the numbers from `a` to `b` but from the `square root of a` to `square root of b`.